# How to add list in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a WordPress Theme. I have list like this

```
<h4>Web Development</h4>
<ul class="menu" id="web_development">
<li><a target="_top" href="http://ajax/index.htm" title="Learn Ajax">Learn Ajax</a></li>
<li><a target="_top" href="http://angularjs/index.htm" title="Learn AngularJS">Learn AngularJS</a></li>
<li><a target="_top" href="http://asp.net/index.htm" title="Learn ASP.Net">Learn ASP.Net</a></li>
<li><a target="_top" href="http://backbonejs/index.htm" title="Learn BackboneJS">Learn BackboneJS</a></li>
<li><a target="_top" href="http://bootstrap/index.htm" title="bootstrap">Learn Bootstrap</a></li>
<li><a target="_top" href="http://css/index.htm" title="Learn CSS">Learn CSS</a></li>
```

I am trying this list to WordPress but I am not getting the exact solution. What I have done is I added Custom Post Type UI and Advanced Custom Field Plugins.

I created New Post type with "course Library" name and there I added Custom Fields and on the coding section I have done this

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_library', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
<?php while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div style="height: 2572px;" class="featured-box">
<h4><?php echo the_field('main_heading'); ?></h4>
<ul class="menu" id="java_technologies">
<li><a target="_top" href="/"><?php echo the_field('your_topic_title_1'); ?></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

now I can add new list like for example

**Learn Programming**

but it only let me create one topic. How do I let it create as many as topic I want under that heading.

Also I want to add content for every topic I create. How do I let it me to add content for every topic.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using ACF4 or ACF5 (pro)?

Comment: Did you purchase the [Repeater Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) add-on?

Comment: not yet but do I need it? if yes how do I use it thank you

Comment: I just posted an answer, but I might have misunderstood what you are asking - you want to loop through the posts in your course library and display a list of the "main_heading" field for each?

Comment: Yes almost, Like main_heading Bootstrap >> it will have bootstrap topics.
main_heading CSS >> it will have further CSS topics

Comment: Check out this link for listing custom post type - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-posts-from-custom-post-types-anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to more closely replicate the HTML from your first example and only loop over the `<li>` elements. They will repeat for each post that is returned from your query. Not that [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) will echo the value, you don't need to include `echo` in your code. Use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) to return the field value rather than echoing it.

```php
<?php
// fetch courses
$courses = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_library', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC'));
// do we have any courses?
if ( $course->have_posts() ){
?>
    <!-- this goes outside your loop -->
    <h4>Web Development</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="web_development">
    <?php
    // loop over each course/post
    while ( $courses->have_posts() ){
        $courses->the_post();
        // output the <li> for this course
        ?>
        <li><a target="_top" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('your_topic_title_1'); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
} else {
    // no courses
}
?>
```

Comment: Great. I need to install repeater and then follow this code right?

Comment: Umm something is wrong. because the code is not working. I just installed repeater and created rows. I added text on both. but its not working not even main_heading is displaying neither the 'your_topic_title_1' is displaying anything